# How can I infuse both Pack Mentality and Strength +35% into my red chocobo?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm trying to infuse my red chocobo with both *Pack Mentality* and *Strength +35%*, but I infused it with *Pack Mentality* before infusing it with *Strength +35%* from a Tonberry. Here's my red chocobo's current abilities (RL = red locked, YL = yellow locked):

- RL: Stagger Maintenance II *
- YL: Feral Speed II *
- Role Resonance *
- Item Collector
- Resist Deshell: +66%
- Resist Ice: +45%
- Resist Fire: +45%
- Critical: Bravery
- Resist Deprotect: +44%
- Pack Mentality *

I marked those I do want to stick with an asterisk, the rest are totally negotiable, as long as I can get the *Strength +35%* ability on the list.
Did I screw up my red chocobo?

Answer (score 4):

Every passive ability has a hidden rank: putting aside red-locked abilities, abilities with higher ranks take precedence over abilities with lower ranks. [sakurayule's Monster FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63731) has a list of all the ranks in the game, but the list you see in game corresponds to this precedence:

1. Red-locked *Stagger Maintenance II*
2. Yellow-locked *Feral Speed II* (rank 16)
3. *Role Resonance* (rank 7)
4. *Item Collector* (rank 6)
5. *Resist Deshell +66%* (rank 6)
6. *Resist Ice +45%* (rank 5)
7. *Resist Fire +45%* (rank 5)
8. *Critical: Bravery* (rank 5)
9. *Resist Deprotect +44%* (rank 4)
10. *Pack Mentality* (rank 4)

*Strength +35%* has a rank of 7, which means it would take precedence over everything except *Role Resonance* and the yellow-locked *Feral Speed II*. If you infused your Red Chocobo with it right now, you will lose *Pack Mentality*.

The only way to prevent this would be to yellow-lock *Pack Mentality* so it gains a higher precedence. Unfortunately, there are only two monsters in the game that have an infusable *Pack Mentality*—Chichu and Nanochu—and both are unique crystals.<sup>1</sup> If you've already used both crystals, or you were hoping to use the crystals on different monsters, you are indeed out of luck.

#### Notes

<sup>Note 1:</sup> Unless you purchase the *Perpetual Battlefield* DLC, which allows you to fight [Valfodr](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Valfodr_%28Boss%29). The drops for defeating Valfodr at level 70 include monster crystals for both Nanochu and Chichu.

Comment: This sounds more annoying than unique TMs in Pokemon..

Comment: @BenBrocka It is.  Due to the hidden rank, unless you have a list, you can easily overwrite abilities that you don't want to.  And Pack Mentality is a prime example, due to it being infusable from only two monsters, both one-time crystals.